# Testcafe live not running

Tags: npm, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am on OsX, using nvm, node 10.15.3.
Testscafe (not live) works fine, but I was trying to follow the instructions at [Testcafe-live](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-live)

At the step where it  explains how to install it locally

> If you have installed testcafe-live locally to your project, add an
>   npm script to package.json to run tests:

it refers to a package.json file, I added the entry under the scripts section

```
   "scripts": {
    "test": "eslint ./**/*.js",
    "testcafe-live": "testcafe-live chrome tests/"
  },
```

but when I run

> npm run testcafe-live

I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/Thomas.Pavan/testcafe/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Thomas.Pavan/testcafe/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Thomas.Pavan/.npm/_logs/2019-03-11T14_58_28_946Z-debug.log
```

I see that the package.json path is the problem, my package.json file is in ~/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-live but npm is looking at /Users/Thomas.Pavan/testcafe/.
I'm confused if I installed testcafe-live in the wrong location (currently at ~/testcafe) my project root folder, and I also don't understand where I can change the path shown in the error.
Long story short, the package.json file should be in the root of my folder but installing testcafe-live as instructed, creates a node_modules folder and the package.json file is nested there.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your interest in TestCafe.
Starting from version 1.0.0 TestCafe has a built-in Live mode feature and it does not require any external module. The repository you mentioned is obsolete now. 
Please refer to the following article to get more details https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/live-mode.html

Comment: Thanks, it works! Maybe put some notice on the repo would be useful to redirect people to the most recent version. Thanks again!