# Keep browser open while developing a test in Testcafe

Tags: debugging, browser, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How to keep the browser window open after a test executes in Testcafe?

There was a question on the forum [here](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/keep-browser-open-while-developing-and-testing/643) that brought me to [a live Testcafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-live#testcafe-live) version, but it seems to be deprecated.

I wish to keep the browser window open to see the elements while I'm developing the test.

**Update:**

This is my config file:

```
{
  "name": "testcafe-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "testcafe": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome tests/",
    "testcafe": "testcafe"
  },
  "author": "mmrse",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I tried starting the tests from the command line with

```
E:\testcafe-demo> npm run testcafe chrome demo.testcafe.ts --live
```

and with

```
E:\testcafe-demo> npm test chrome demo.testcafe.ts --live
```

but the result is always the same - after the test is finished, the browser is closed and there is no indication "live" mode was being activated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105328/testcafe-live-not-running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Features from TestCafe Live were integrated into the main TestCafe product.

See [Live Mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/live-mode.html) for more information.

Make sure to add the --live argument into your script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome tests/ --live",
    "testcafe": "testcafe"
  },
```

And run your tests using npm run test.

Here's another example:

**screeshot.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;

test('Take a screenshot of a fieldset', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'Peter Parker')
        .click('#submit-button')
        .takeScreenshot({
            path:     'my-fixture/thank-you-page1.png',
            fullPage: true
        });
});
```

**Command-line arguments:**

```
testcafe chrome screenshot.js --live
```

**Output:**

```
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.

Live mode is enabled.
TestCafe now watches source files and reruns
the tests once the changes are saved.

You can use the following keys in the terminal:
'Ctrl+S' - stops the test run;
'Ctrl+R' - restarts the test run;
'Ctrl+W' - enables/disables watching files;
'Ctrl+C' - quits live mode and closes the browsers.


Watching the following files:
  c:\Temp\screenshot.js
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 79.0.3945.130 / Windows 10

 My fixture
 √ Take a screenshot of a fieldset (screenshots: c:\Temp\screenshots\my-fixture\thank-you-page1.png)


 1 passed (5s)

Make changes to the source files or press Ctrl+R to restart the test run.
```

Comment: Hmmm, I added `--live` flag at the end of my command line, but the browser still closes at the end of the test.

Comment: Make sure that you use the latest version (1.8.1+) with the Live mode integrated.

Comment: I have the 1.8.2. version but still.

Comment: What OS and browser version are you running your tests on? Do you have a testcafe config file? If so, what's inside?

Comment: Chrome 80.0.3987.116 / Windows 10. I have a basic (default) config file, the only change is the author name.

Comment: I have the same environment. Try to move your config file so that it is not used, and run the example I've added to the answer. What output do you get in the command prompt?

Comment: Please see my updated question. I never get `Live mode is enabled.` in cmd output.

Comment: What about my example? Did you run it?

Comment: I did. It runs fine, but not in live mode.

Comment: Please run these commands in your command-prompt using my sample and make a screenshot of the results in the command-prompt:
`testcafe -v`
`testcafe chrome screenshot.js --live`

Comment: Also, as a second test, add the '--live' argument into your config directly:
"scripts": {
"test": "testcafe chrome tests/ --live",
"testcafe": "testcafe"
},
and run "npm run test"

Comment: Adding '--live' argument to config script worked! Please add that to your answer and I will accept it. Thanks.