# Can I bypass waiting for the page to load in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to bypass the page load wait?  The product I am testing is in an iframe, independent of the page that it loads on.  However, the host page takes forever to load, unnecessarily increasing my test times.  So I am looking for a way to bypass the page load and instead wait on the iframe to finish loading.  ideas?

Comment: It looks like DevExpress have a ticket in their Sprint, to override the default page load time (https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2940). I'm not sure if this will apply to the initial page load, or just for navigation

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe is an end to end testing tool. That means the original page load time is a part of that. I don't think it would be a realistic test if you excluded that part.

That being said, I understand the frustration of waiting in the given scenario. Maybe TestCafe [Live mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303335/keep-browser-open-while-developing-a-test-in-testcafe) could help you, at least during the development of tests.

For, example if you wish to run `screenshot.js` you will need to add `--live` switch:

```
testcafe chrome screenshot.js --live
```

Comment: Thanks Mate!  I am transitioning from wdio to testcafe and noticed this slowdown.  There may not be a workaround but i'll give your suggestion and try and post if i find anything.  thanks for the hint!